# How do I repair an external hard drive with a corrupted catalog?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, mount, macos-catalina, fsck

I'm attempting to mount my nearly filled up 1TB Mac OS Extended External Hard Drive to my MacBook Air 13" which is running MacOS Catalina 10.15.7. When I do this, the media drive mounts onto the computer (`disk2`), but the actual drive itself (`disk2s2`) is refusing to mount. Running 'First Aid' on `disk2s2` results in "Invalid catalogue PEOF". `sudo fsck_hfs -r -d /dev/disk2s2` returns same results.

From Disk Utility:

> **Running First Aid on “” (disk2s2)**
>
> Repairing file system.
> Volume is already unmounted.
> Performing fsck_hfs -fy -x /dev/rdisk2s2
> Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
> Invalid catalogue PEOF
> The volume   could not be verified completely.
> File system check exit code is 8.
> Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
> File system verify or repair failed. : (-69845)
>
> **Operation failed…**

From `sudo fsck_hfs -r -d /dev/disk2s2`:

> ```
> journal_replay(/dev/disk2s2) returned 0
> ** /dev/rdisk2s2
> Using cacheBlockSize=32K cacheTotalBlock=16384 cacheSize=524288K.
>    Executing fsck_hfs (version hfs-522.100.5).
> ** Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
>    Invalid catalog PEOF
> (4, 0)
> ** The volume   could not be verified completely.
> volume check failed with error 7
> volume type is pure HFS+
> primary MDB is at block 0 0x00
> alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00
> primary VHB is at block 2 0x02
> alternate VHB is at block 1952853342 0x74662d5e
> sector size = 512 0x200
> VolumeObject flags = 0x07
> total sectors for volume = 1952853344 0x74662d60
> total sectors for embedded volume = 0 0x00
> CheckHFS returned -1317, fsmodified = 0
> ```

Please keep in mind that I'm trying to stay away from DiskWarrior or any other paid tool, so it would be amazing if it can be repaired manually or with a free tool.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I've run a quick search on the disk with `testdisk`. The disk with the problem is `/dev/disk3`. Here's what it says:

```
Thu May  6 16:43:45 2021
Command line: TestDisk

TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org
OS: Darwin, kernel 19.6.0 (Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Tue Jan 12 22:13:05 PST 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.16~1/RELEASE_X86_64) x86_64
Compiler: GCC 4.2
ext2fs lib: none, ntfs lib: none, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none, curses lib: ncurses 5.7
Hard disk list
Disk /dev/disk2 - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - 3907029168 sectors (RO), sector size=512
Disk /dev/disk3 - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - 1953525168 sectors, sector size=512
Disk /dev/rdisk2 - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - 3907029168 sectors (RO), sector size=512
Disk /dev/rdisk3 - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - 1953525168 sectors, sector size=512
Disk /dev/rdisk4 - 2000 GB / 1862 GiB - 488327436 sectors (RO), sector size=4096

Partition table type (auto): EFI GPT
Disk /dev/disk3 - 1000 GB / 931 GiB
Partition table type: EFI GPT

Analyse Disk /dev/disk3 - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - 1953525168 sectors
hdr_size=92
hdr_lba_self=1
hdr_lba_alt=1953525167 (expected 1953525167)
hdr_lba_start=34
hdr_lba_end=1953525134
hdr_lba_table=2
hdr_entries=128
hdr_entsz=128
Current partition structure:
 1 P EFI System                    40     409639     409600 [EFI System Partition]
 2 P Mac HFS                   409640 1953262983 1952853344

search_part()
Disk /dev/disk3 - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - 1953525168 sectors
FAT32 at 40/0/1
check_FAT: Unusual media descriptor (0xf0!=0xf8)
FAT1 : 32-3182
FAT2 : 3183-6333
start_rootdir : 6334 root cluster : 2
Data : 6334-409599
sectors : 409600
cluster_size : 1
no_of_cluster : 403266 (2 - 403267)
fat_length 3151 calculated 3151
heads/cylinder 16 (FAT) != 1 (HD)
sect/track 32 (FAT) != 1 (HD)

FAT32 at 40/0/1
     EFI System                    40     409639     409600 [EFI System Partition] [EFI]
     FAT32, blocksize=512, 209 MB / 200 MiB

HFSX magic value at 409640/0/1

HFSX magic value at 409640/0/1
part_size 1952853344
     Mac HFS                   409640 1953262983 1952853344
     HFSX blocksize=4096 + Backup, 999 GB / 931 GiB

Results
   P EFI System                    40     409639     409600 [EFI System Partition] [EFI]
     FAT32, blocksize=512, 209 MB / 200 MiB
   P Mac HFS                   409640 1953262983 1952853344
     HFSX blocksize=4096 + Backup, 999 GB / 931 GiB
```

**Edit 2:**
Disk Utility instantly fails to create an image.

> Creating disk image from “ADATA HD710 Media” (disk3)
>
>
> Operation cancelled.

`testdisk` takes really long time to create an image. Takes 10 minutes just to finish 0.01%. This is a last resort for me. It would be better if the drive could be repaired with the data still preserved in it.

**Edit 3:**
I'm ok if a small amount of recent data gets removed/corrupted, because they were large files being downloaded to the computer, then being transferred to the hard drive.

**Edit 4:**
DiskDrill fails to rebuild the HFS+ catalog.

**Edit 5:**
I've gone through the hard drive with Hex Fiend, and everything is still there. But I don't know what to change in the hex data so that the PEOF becomes correct. I can see the file names, and I can file contents in there, for example, I can see some JSON from one of my JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

[DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com) is quite probably the only tool that could fix the drive non-destructively. Everything else is going to just be to scavenge what it can find of your data, not fix the drive. [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is probably the only free tool worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

If the disk is not mounting, then you will likely have to spend some money on
a repair utility or a data recovery application, if the data is important and
has no backup.

Although you have specified that you are not interested
in commercial software, I list below some such tools, if no better answer
comes up. You may ask around your friends or nearby repair-shops that might
have one of the below-mentioned products, which you may use freely or
at least cheaply.
These products have demo versions that you can try to see how effective they
would be, to see if they are worth searching for (or buying).

[Stellar Data Recovery](https://www.stellarinfo.com/free-mac-data-recovery.php)
has a demo version that will recover up to 1 GB of lost or deleted data, free of cost.
The full version will cost €79.

[Data Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/mac-data-recovery)
by Prosoft Engineering has straight recovery options, but also
advanced options to try to recover data from disks with physical failures.
It has a demo version and has an interesting pricing model, where the
price is determined by the amount of data that you wish to recover,
starting from as low as $19.

[DiskWarrior](https://www.alsoft.com/)
has a data recovery type option - it will try to rebuild and present
a preview of what it thinks should be on the disk even if it can’t repair,
and it might allow you to copy the data off. It is very costly at $119.95.

[EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard for Mac](https://www.easeus-software.com/data-recovery-software/mac-data-recovery-wizard.html)
is a subscription product, starting from $89.95 per year.

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that is available is [**Disk Drill**](https://www.cleverfiles.com/pro.html), it has tree editions

[image]