# Hard Disk showing wrong capacity and is RAW disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

will write step by step:

1. one day my linux mint Drive stopped responding.
2. i forced re-started the Laptop.
3. On boot screen it showed [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t26RB.jpg)
4. Then after some time showed : No boot device Present
5. Then i showed it to someone locally, they said hdd has gone corrupt.
6. Then i gave it to a local data recovery agent, he showed me data over remote desktop, but was asking for huge money (read extortion as was increasing money day by day), i took it back without recovery of data due to not having that much money.
7. I attached it to my usb external drive casing and Bang!! **it is now showing hdd is of 2.2 TB and is a RAW & unformatted Disk** (otherwise it had 4 partitions and is of 1 TB capacity)
8. i attached it to SATA port inside Laptop, it is detected in BIOS, but not anywhere else. I tried accessing via linux live boot, while connected in SATA Port.
9. Accessing SMART data only shows Hard disk model number rest all fields shows [No information]
10. I don't think that it is an hardware issue as the hd had no marks of opening of hard disk. Label was clearly intact. so i think either it is a bad sectors issue OR a soft issue (plz correct me if i am wrong).**asking for your opinion is it hardware or software issue??**
11. i am now in need of some of my projects from this drive.**asking for your help in identifying issue so that i can recover data myself**
12. somewhere suggested & i tried `testdisk` it shows hard disk as *Generic External* (rather than WDXXXX) and didn't find any partitions on quick or deep scan.
13. somewhere suggested to use `ddresue` for cloning and then working on this drive, but that needs a drive having capacity > 1 TB to make its image, which is not possible for me to buy/borrow.
14. somewhere suggested & using `GParted` i get input/output error.

**Please please please Help!!**

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think that it is an hardware issue as the hd had no marks of opening of hard disk. Label was clearly intact.

"Hardware issue" has nothing to do with the disk having been opened.

For example, the physical sectors on the disk platters can sometimes go bad on their own. Not only those which store your data, but also the "system area"[1](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/227087517.pdf) which stores the disk's internal parameters (such as SMART counters or even the disk's firmware).

If the disk's firmware itself no longer knows what's where, then you won't be able to do anything from the outside. Find an actual data recovery company (not just "some guy").

(As another example of hardware issues, sometimes the disk's read/write heads can physically crash into the platters and gouge a deep groove where your data used to be. It happens rarely, but when it does you can hear the disk dying from two rooms away.)

Answer (score 0):

In the error
`ACPI MSFT0101:00 Platform device creation failed: -16`:

- `MSFT0101` is an ACPI device ID referring to the
  Intel(R) Management Engine Interface (part of TPM).
- Code `-16` stands for TPM (Trusted Platform Module)
  used for security technologies such as bitlocker.

Perhaps the TPM device on your computer is having some issues.

If you don't use TPM (and only if!), you may disable it to get rid of
the warning.

To disable TPM, enter BIOS setup (press F2 during POST) and search for
this option.
Toggling TPM off may on some BIOS require setting a Supervisor password,
which you may later delete by setting it to blank
(don't set this password unless absolutely required).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @harrymc. I have used a new drive, which is working fine without changing any of settings in BIOS. Everything in Laptop is working fine since then. So there seems to be no issue with any of the Laptop's non hdd part.

Comment: Seems like the BIOS was thinking that the disk was bitlocked or something and not succeeding in understanding it. The disk is then dead.

Comment: in your opinion is there any chance of data recovery? by myself using some tools in linux or by data recovery companies?

Comment: Data recovery companies have a very good chance of recovering some data. Try first by yourself, using the tools in my other [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1647170/8672). Try first the tool of Stellar Data Recovery, because it will already recover 1 GB for free. If any of the demos of any tool can at least show you your files, buying the tool will be cheaper than sending it to a company.

Comment: any free tool in linux? cant spend that much money, can spend time.

Comment: Try first one or more of the the tools to see if the data is salvageable, then you can look for free tools.

Comment: _Then i gave it to a local data recovery agent, he showed me data over remote desktop_ high chances of data being there?? can there be partition table error etc?